# WCF message encryption - key

Tags: wcf, encryption, passwords, key, message

I'm quite new in WCF.

I created a WCF application with message encryption and username/password authentication. I have multiple clients connecting with my server and I want to encrypt messages with unique key for every connection.

Here is my binding:

```
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding0">
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

And here is service credentials section in seviceBehaviour

```
      <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="ls Server" storeLocation="CurrentUser" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Server.CustomUserValidation, Server" />
      </serviceCredentials>
```

And here is my question, how the key for encryption algorithm is generated? It will be unique for every client? If not, what I have to do to accomplish my task?
Thanks in advance.

Edit1:

Maybe can I set the user password to be the encryption key? It would be the best solution for me.